# Prove that half-open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Self-learning these concepts, so please be tolerant with imprecise terminology...

Defining the standard topology on the real line $\mathbb {R}$ as all the open intervals, a Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated where all open intervals $(a,b)$ can be assigned a measure, $|a-b|$.

Within the "rules" of a sigma algebra it can be proven through:

$$\bigcap_{n\geq1}(a -\frac{1}{n},\,b)= [a,b)$$.

The question is, since $n$ is an integer, would we not just approach the real number $a$ asymptotically, but never reach it from the left?

Comment: Notice two things:  $a\in (a-\frac{1}{n},b)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.   For all $\epsilon>0$ you have $a-\epsilon \notin (a-\frac{1}{n},b)$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Despite never having "reached it," the sets can be seen to be equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any positive integer $n$, we have $a - \frac{1}{n} < a < b$, so $a \in \left(a - \frac{1}{n}, b\right)$. Therefore $a$ is in all of the intervals $\left(a - \frac{1}{n}, b\right)$, so it is in their intersection.

On the other hand, if $x < a$, then $\epsilon = a - x > 0$, so for some positive integer $n$ we have $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, and consequently  $x < a - \frac{1}{n}$, so $x \not\in \left(a - \frac{1}{n}, b\right)$, and therefore $x$ is not in the intersection.

Comment: I will accept your answer as soon as the system allows it, but I wonder if you can say something about the operation of countably infinite intersections being possible within the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, while not allowed within the generating topology. Am I saying this right?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I think I understand your question. You are correct that a countable (or any infinite) intersection of open sets is not necessarily open.  On the other hand, a $\sigma$-algebra is by definition closed under countable intersections and unions. This is why sets such as $[a,b)$ are in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra even though they are not open. Why are $\sigma$-algebras defined to be closed under countable unions and intersections? Because we want to be able to measure sets formed by these operations! If we could only measure open sets then that would be unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: The system of open subsets generally isn't closed to countable intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see why those to sets are equal. Suppose first that $x\in\underset{n\geq 1}{\bigcap}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$. This means that for each $n\geq 1$ we have $x\in (a-\frac{1}{n},b)$. Suppose on contrary that $x<a$. Then, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x<a-\frac{1}{n}$, which contradicts that $x\in(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$. Thus, $x\geq a$, and hence, $x\in [a,b)$.

Conversely, if $x\in [a,b)$, then for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have $a-\frac{1}{n}<a\leq x<b$, so that $x\in (a-\frac{1}{n},b)$. Since this holds for every $n$, it follows that $x\in\underset{n\geq 1}{\bigcap}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$$ consists the all real number that is greater than $a-\frac{1}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$, and less than b.
If $x<a$ then there exists $n$ that $x<a-\frac{1}{n}$. 
$a>a-\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n$. $(a,b)$ is a subset of $(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$ for every $n$ and if $x$ isn't less than $b$ than it isn't contained by $S$.
So, it means, $$S=[a,b).$$